# Extract year from a string in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, string

STR_TO_DATE() returns null for this string "Apr 17 1989 12:00AM".

How to get the year from the string "Apr 17 1989 12:00AM" with regular expression in mysql?

Comment: leverage the [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fstr-to-date) function and the [date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Comment: @Crawdingle STR_TO_DATE() returns null for this string "Apr 17 1989 12:00AM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me...

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Apr 17 1989 12:00AM','%M %d %Y %h:%i%p');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('Apr 17 1989 12:00PM','%M %d %Y %h:%i%p') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 1989-04-17 00:00:00                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```